# How to configure Spring Data Rest for working with two databases?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-rest

Currently I have project with configured data sources for two databases, it works fine.

But after adding spring data rest module it does not work, I am getting such error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class....
```

It appears only after adding @RepositoryRestResource annotation. Seems like Spring Data Rest is not synchronized with jpa repositories configuration, does anybody have example of working spring data rest jpa repositories with two databases?